# VertexBuffer causes program to crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I am having a crash issue with the VertexBuffer line.  If I comment out the line, my program will iterate through this code 49 times.  The code is from Riemer's tutorial for XNA 4.0 and does work in that solution.  I have checked the 'using' statements and don't see any thing different between the two projects.  I can't figure out why the VertexBuffer will crash the program while the IndexBuffer is just fine.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
    public void CopyToTerrainBuffers()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
            {
                if (!gpu_buffer_std[x, y].initialized)
                {
                    VertexBuffer temp = new VertexBuffer(   device, 
                                                            typeof(VertexMultitextured), 
                                                            tiles_std[x + 1, y + 1].terrainVertices.Length * VertexMultitextured.SizeInBytes, 
                                                            BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
                    // size = 3,698,744
                    gpu_buffer_std[x, y].terrainVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, 
                                                                                typeof(VertexMultitextured), 
                                                                                tiles_std[x + 1, y + 1].terrainVertices.Length * VertexMultitextured.SizeInBytes, 
                                                                                BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
                    gpu_buffer_std[x, y].terrainIndexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(  device, 
                                                                                typeof(int), 
                                                                                tiles_std[x + 1, y + 1].indices.Length, 
                                                                                BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
                    gpu_buffer_std[x, y].initialized = true;
                }
                if (!tiles_std[x + 1, y + 1].toGPU)
                {
                    //gpu_buffer_std[x, y].terrainVertexBuffer.SetData(tiles_std[x + 1, y + 1].terrainVertices);
                    gpu_buffer_std[x, y].terrainIndexBuffer.SetData(tiles_std[x + 1, y + 1].indices);
                    gpu_buffer_std[x, y].terrainVertexDeclaration = VertexMultitextured.VertexDeclaration;
                    tiles_std[x + 1, y + 1].toGPU = true;
                }
            }
    }
```

The 'temp' was to see if it was the pointer causing the problem.  This is the whole function (brute force method).  Here is the struct being used.

```
    public struct VertexMultitextured : IVertexType
    {
        public Vector3 position;
        public Vector3 normal;
        public Vector4 textureCoordinate;
        public Vector4 texWeights;

        public static int SizeInBytes = sizeof(float) * (3 + 3 + 4 + 4);

        public readonly static VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration
        (
            new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 3, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * (3 + 3), VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0),
            new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * (3 + 3 + 4), VertexElementFormat.Vector4, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 1)
        );

        public VertexMultitextured(Vector3 position, Vector3 normal, Vector4 textureCoordinate, Vector4 texWeights)
        {
            this.position = position;
            this.normal = normal;
            this.textureCoordinate = textureCoordinate;
            this.texWeights = texWeights;
        }

        public Vector3 Position
        {
            get { return position; }
            set { position = value; }
        }

        public Vector3 Normal
        {
            get { return normal; }
            set { normal = value; }
        }

        public Vector4 TextureCoordinate
        {
            get { return textureCoordinate; }
            set { textureCoordinate = value; }
        }

        public Vector4 TexWeights
        {
            get { return texWeights; }
            set { texWeights = value; }
        }

        VertexDeclaration IVertexType.VertexDeclaration
        {
            get { return VertexDeclaration; }
        }
    }
```

---

Update: I have taken the code in question and placed it in Reimers code, and have produced the same results.  The debugger shows the following:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
HResult=-2147024882
Message=Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
Source=Microsoft.Xna.Framework
StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Helpers.GetExceptionFromResult(UInt32 result)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsHelpers.GetExceptionFromResult(UInt32 result)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexBuffer.CreateBuffer(VertexDeclaration vertexDeclaration, UInt32 dwVertexCount, UInt32 usage, _D3DPOOL pool)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexBuffer..ctor(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, Type vertexType, Int32 vertexCount, BufferUsage usage)
   at Series3D4.Game1.CopyToTerrainBuffers(VertexMultitextured[] vertices, Int32[] indices) in D:\C#Programs\Series3D4\Series3D4\Series3D4\Game1.cs:line 494
   at Series3D4.Game1.LoadVertices() in D:\C#Programs\Series3D4\Series3D4\Series3D4\Game1.cs:line 190
   at Series3D4.Game1.LoadContent() in D:\C#Programs\Series3D4\Series3D4\Series3D4\Game1.cs:line 172
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Initialize()
   at Series3D4.Game1.Initialize() in D:\C#Programs\Series3D4\Series3D4\Series3D4\Game1.cs:line 154
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
   at Series3D4.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\C#Programs\Series3D4\Series3D4\Series3D4\Program.cs:line 13
InnerException:
```

Here is the class being used:

```
    public class DisplayTileChunk
    {
        // Header info for tile control
        public bool beenmoved; // x,z been updated after move
        public bool isvisible; // render the tile on screen
        public bool loaded; // tile loaded/processed in memory
        public bool toGPU; // tile data transfered to GPU
        // Terrain info
        public int[] texture_index = new int[4];
        public VertexMultitextured[] terrainVertices = new VertexMultitextured[4225]; // 65 x 65
        public int[] indices = new int[24576]; // 64 x 64 x 6
        public VertexBuffer terrainVertexBuffer;
        public IndexBuffer terrainIndexBuffer;
        public VertexDeclaration terrainVertexDeclaration;
        public int noVertices; // = terrainVertexBuffer.VertexCount;
        public int noTriangles; // = terrainIndexBuffer.IndexCount / 3;
        // Water Info
        public VertexBuffer waterVertexBuffer;
        public VertexDeclaration waterVertexDeclaration;
        // Vegetation Info
        public VertexBuffer treeVertexBuffer;
        public VertexDeclaration treeVertexDeclaration;
    }
```

And the modified function from Reimers code:

```
    private void CopyToTerrainBuffers(VertexMultitextured[] vertices, int[] indices)
    {
        terrainVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, typeof(VertexMultitextured), vertices.Length * VertexMultitextured.SizeInBytes, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        terrainVertexBuffer.SetData(vertices);

        terrainIndexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(device, typeof(int), indices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        terrainIndexBuffer.SetData(indices);

        for (int x = 0; x < 36; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < 36; y++)
            {
                gpu_buffer_std[x, y] = new DisplayTileChunk();
                VertexBuffer test = new VertexBuffer(device, typeof(VertexMultitextured), 4225 * VertexMultitextured.SizeInBytes, BufferUsage.None);
                //gpu_buffer_std[x, y].terrainVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, typeof(VertexMultitextured), gpu_buffer_std[x, y].terrainVertices.Length * VertexMultitextured.SizeInBytes, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
                //gpu_buffer_std[x, y].terrainIndexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(device, typeof(int), gpu_buffer_std[x, y].indices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
            }

    }
```

And some interesting numbers from the debugger:

```
vertices.Length = 16384
terrainVertexBuffer.VertexCount = 917504
terrainVertexBuffer._vertexCount = 917504
terrainVertexBuffer._size = 51380224

test.VertexCount = 236600
test._vertexCount = 236600
test._size = 13249600
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting, which iteration does it crash on?

Comment: No error message, program simply "stops working", it crashes on the first pass. If they both caused the program to crash it would be straight forward.

Comment: You need to post more details. Can you link the tutorial you're using, provide more code, and provide a more specific description of what "stops working" means. Is it throwing an unhandled exception? Or can you step through it and identify the line of the crash? What does the debugger say?

Comment: Link: http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series4.php

Comment: I only get the windows "Program has stopped working.../Microsoft is looking for a solution" message.  Debugger stays at the black screen for me.

Comment: So which `CopyToTerrainBuffers` is failing? the first one or the second one? According to your debugging numbers you are allocating 1.6MB on each iteration, for 49 iterations ( 7 * 7 ) you are allocating 78.4 MB of GPU memory, for 1296 iterations ( 36 * 36 ) you are allocation ~2GB of GPU memory. Depending on your hardware, its quite possible that you are simply exceeding your cards available memory.

Comment: I should have deleted the first one when I updated this.  The problem is the out of memory error.  That I have coded to catch with the try-catch-finally to see how many buffers I can allocate to the GPU.  What I don't understand from the numbers is for 'test':

Comment: 4225 vertices x 56 bytes(sizeof) = 236,600; the '_size' multiplies this by 56 again to give the result shown (13.2MB).  I am using GTX580s with 1.5GB memory.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, original line:

```
        terrainVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, 
                                               typeof(VertexMultitextured), 
                                               vertices.Length * VertexMultitextured.SizeInBytes, 
                                               BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
```

Correct line:

```
        terrainVertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, 
                                               typeof(VertexMultitextured), 
                                               vertices.Length, // error was here
                                               BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
```

I couldn't see the error for looking at it, took a few days off and 'boom', there it was.